# How do I set the width of my web app with Vuetify 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to create a web app that has an app bar and a main area that have the same basic layout as Stack Overflow: a maximum width on wider screens that then adjusts as the screen becomes narrower.  I've gotten something like this working with Vuetify 2 but it's been surprisingly difficult for me to understand how to do this with Vuetify 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be:

- to set the width of the inner contents of the app bar, use an inner v-container that has a `max-width` CSS style set for it
- to set the width of the app, set the same `max-width` on a `v-container`.
- to have sidebars hide as the screen gets narrower, use `@media` queries that set `display: none` on the stuff that should be hidden and `width: 100%` on the stuff that should take up the whole width of the screen at that point.

Below's a CodePen showing a Stack Overflow-style layout where various divs disappear as the screen gets narrower.  It isn't using Vuetify components for the inner divs but you could use `v-row` and `v-col` Vuetify components if you wanted a traditional two/three-column layout.  The app bar and the main container are Vuetify components and their widths are set by manual CSS rather than Vuetify helper classes, as described above.

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://codepen.io/NathanWailes/pen/ExdzqBM

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar
      density="compact"
      elevation=0
    >
      <v-container class="inner-app-bar">
        <template v-slot:prepend>
          <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        </template>

        <v-app-bar-title>Stack Overflow</v-app-bar-title>

        <template v-slot:append>
          <v-btn icon="mdi-dots-vertical"></v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-container>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main>
      <v-container class="main-container">
        <div class="left-sidebar"></div>
        <div class="inner-content">
          <div class="question-header"></div>
          <div class="mainbar"></div>
          <div class="sidebar"></div>
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

```
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  template: '#app-template',
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```
.inner-app-bar {
  max-width: 1264px;
  background: darkolivegreen;
}
.inner-content {
  background: grey;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 164px);
}
.left-sidebar {
  width: 164px;
  background: darkslategrey;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.question-header {
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #f1e5bc;
}
.v-container.main-container {
  max-width: 1264px;
  padding: 0;
  background: olive;
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .left-sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
  .inner-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to wrap your main content in a `v-col` and set the number of display columns for different breakpoints?

```html
<v-app-bar />
<v-main>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row dense justify="center">
      <v-col id="content-wrapper"
        cols="12" md="8" lg="6"
      >
        <v-sheet
          color="grey-lighten-2"
          height="96"
          class="d-flex justify-center align-center"
        >Content</v-sheet>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-main>
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/KKGLEyp?editors=1010)

If more precise responsiveness is needed you could also accomplish your goal with standard CSS and [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries) using your own custom breakpoints.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #content-wrapper {
    width: 300px
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  #content-wrapper {
    width: 600px
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  #content-wrapper {
    width: 1000px
  }
}
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/XWxwGzp?editors=1010)